# Chrome HTTP OPTIONS (Preflight) Fails, but works in Postman

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

I am building a SPA using AngularJS and .NET MVC/WebApi. I am having an issue with Chrome sending a pre-flight request for POST,PUT,DELETE operations (as it should), and getting a 404 response back from the server. The issue with this is that this request (with identical headers and HTTP method) is successful when using an API testing tool; Postman for this example.

Here is the request/response information through Chrome:
[image]

IIS Trace: 2015-12-22 16:18:01 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS /api/v1/sidebar v=1450801081939 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.106+Safari/537.36 https://etk.localtest.me/ 404 0 0 6

And here is the same request in Postman:

[image]

IIS Trace: 2015-12-22 16:17:14 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS /api/v1/sidebar v=1449874981966 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 7

I would believe that my CORS configuration is configured correctly given it works in Postman?

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue before? Any solutions/fixes?

Comment: I see the call are made to different API endpoint, you sure the one that didn't work in chrome works in postman?

Comment: @maurycy whoops, that was my bad. I updated the screenshot to be the matching request :-X

Comment: for whatever reason server says that this URL is non existant, maybe you should check access logs from your server

Comment: Here is the 404 call: 
2015-12-22 15:53:18 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS /api/v1/sidebar v=1450799596414 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.106+Safari/537.36 https://etk.localtest.me/ 404 0 0 2423

Comment: Well that's what I mean, there is 404 for this call, is the server throwing this error on purpose i.e. on authentication check? What will you get if same URL you will use in browser (go to address)

Comment: Browsing to the address works fine. Also I've removed the Authorize attribute from all endpoints while trying to debug this so there should be no Auth check occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Preflight requests are created by the browser. From my experience Postman doesn't actually send a preflight request, so if anything is wrong with your CORS configuration, your API calls will work with Postman but not with Chrome.